# Confusion regarding the fundamentals of Multiplication Theorem in Combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics

I framed this simple question myself:

> A church has totally 3 doors. A man enters the church through one of
> the 3 doors but makes sure to exit the church through a different one.
> Find the total number of ways he can enter and exit?

I have done some exercises like how many days a 5 digit number can be formed from a given set of numbers say {1,2,3,4,5,6,7} such that repetition is allowed . This inspired me to write 2∗2∗2
. So I thought in our case if the person exits through a fixed Door C, he can accomplish this by entering Door A and Door B... So A->C and B-> C in short. I guess something like this inspired me to write like that.

**Few moments later after revisiting the multiplication theorem, my brain works like this:**

Number of ways to enter $ =3$

Number of ways to exit $=2$

So total number of enter-exit combos: 2*3=6 which is correct.

**My Real Confusion**

Now lets assume that hypothetically the answer was 2^3, how should I modify this question accordingly? And if possible, could you intuitively explain why my thinking is wrong initially?

Comment: I really don't understand your argument for $2\cdot2\cdot2.$ Definitely, the answer is $3\cdot 2.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I have done some exercises like *how many days a 5 digit number can be formed from a given set of numbers say {1,2,3,4,5,6,7} such that repetition is allowed* . This inspired me to write $2*2*2$. So I thought in our case if the person exits through a fixed Door C, he can accomplish this by entering Door A and Door B... So A->C and B-> C in short. I guess something like this inspired me to write like that

Comment: There is no real way, if there are three doors,  and you want an ordered set of doors, with or without allowing repetition, to get something that is *not* a multiple of $3.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Ok what if the question was modified a little and the condition was made such that the person can also exit through the door he used to enter

Comment: "*How many ways can a person enter and then exit the church if there were three doors available and they can use the same door to enter and exit with as well as they can use different doors if they wished?*"  The answer to that would be $3\times 3$... picking which of the three doors to enter with and then picking which of the three doors to exit with.  Recognize that $3\times 3$ is not the same thing as $2\times 2\times 2$

Comment: It doesn't matter - if the person can choose from $3$ doors in the first step and the number of ways to choose second step is the same for all first steps, the number of ways will be a multiple of $3.$ If you make the number of ways for the second step to occur depend on the first step, then you might get $8$ as a count, but I can't think of any way you would naturally be blue to argue that count is $2\cdot2\cdot2.$ Rather, it would be either $3\cdot k-a$ for some $a$ or $a+b+c$ for some $a,b,c.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not understand your question... Are you asking for a word problem relating to this church with three doors such that the answer to the word problem is $2^3$? There is not a good one... certainly not one that has anything to do with the doors without shoehorning in extra details. "Suppose a church has three doors and the main door is broken and can not be used... how many ways can a person enter, exit, and then enter again the church?" This seems like a pointless effort to try to force the numbers to be like this.

An answer of $2^3$
resulting from multiplication principle would typically result from something like a task which has 2
options being followed by another task which has 2
options (with the number of options consistent regardless what outcome occurred in the previous task), followed by a third task again with 2
options. You get the total number of outcomes by multiplying these together. (Or, a task with 4 options followed by a task with 2 options, etc...). You have three doors, and assuming those doors are the options for one of the steps... that would have implied a multiple of 3

"The church has a ventilation problem and it was decided that they needed to leave certain doors and/or windows open. The church has 3 doors. How many ways could they decide to leave some, all, or none of the doors open?" Pick if the first door is left open or closed: 2 options... Pick if the second door is left open or closed... Pick if the third door is open or closed. That would have given $2\times 2\times 2$
... but again, this is getting quite far away from the flavor of your original question.

Comment: Don't answer a question with "I don't understand your question." If ou don't understand the question, help the OP clarify first.

Comment: Read "*I don't understand your question*" as "*I understand your question but the premise is wrong and here is why*"